# Using the „Singularity elemination factor“ in SOLIDWORKS Simulation

Tags: solidworks

I’m new to the nonlinear static simulation in SOLIDWORKS… and therefore I’m trying to understand the advanced options in SOLIDWORKS Simulation. And here the “singularity elimination factor” is mentioned.

I found this link - https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2014/04/singularity-elimination-factor/ - with a short explanation about the SEF. But still there are some general questions for me to clarify and I hope you can help me.

**Questions:**

- The proposed modification of the value SEF enables the simulation to terminate. Values closer to 0 are more effective. But how is this adjustment of SEF affecting the results? Is there anything to be aware of?
- This article mentions four points (stiffness singularities, incremental strain being too large, incremental rotations being too large, contact iterations non-converging) which may cause the simulation fail. How can I relate which of the four points is responsible for the simulation fail?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The most important bit of the linked article is "Most problems are due to setup and can be corrected. Also, you may be overlooking some bad elements in your model." It's a workaround that increases computation time by allowing bad simulations with highly deformed elements to be *completed*, but the results are not what I would call reliable...

Comment: @ Jonathan R Swift: Perhaps at a certain stage it is not possible to correct the model or you have no clue what correction is needed and you only want to terminate the simulation. But with a view to interpreting the results (carefully)… Is it possible to get a more quantitative than rather a qualitative statement on the reliability of the results?